# How can I make `<Shift>+<LeftArrow>` and `<Shift>+<RightArrow>` key bindings work using MacVim?

Tags: insert-mode

How can I make `<Shift>+<LeftArrow>` and `<Shift>+<RightArrow>` key bindings work using MacVim?

I often use these (default) key bindings in Insert mode to move the cursor one word to the right/left on Linux.

However, using MacVim on macOS nothing happens, when these key bindings are pressed.

Any ideas?